# All promoted results from a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, promoted-results

Is there a way I can import promoted results from a SharePoint List? Or rather, a promoted result feching data from SharePoint list. Basically my requirement is, I have large set of enterprise applications and I want to create promoted results for each. There are URL's to each application and I want to have promoted results for each.

Answer (score 2):

No. there is no way to set Promoted result from a SharePoint list.

If you want the result from the list to show at the top of all search results, you can consider using Result Block instead of Promoted result.
https://howtodowithsharepoint.wordpress.com/2015/05/23/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-custom-result-blocks-using-query-rules/

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you really needed Promoted Results, is to use PowerShell to "convert" List Items to Promoted Results. I did this a while back for Thesaurus entries. The list was managed by a customer and then a scheduled job queried the list and created the thesaurus entries. You could do something similar to create the Promoted Results using PnP PowerShell for SPO.

Look at the Set-PnPSearchConfiguration cmdlet.

[SharePoint PnP PowerShell](https://github.com/sharepoint/pnp-powershell/)